# How to preload .swf file and cache it for future page requests?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, flash, swfupload

I am using [swfupload](http://swfupload.org/) to upload files on a website, the problem that every time the user open the page which contains the upload button, the page loads completely then the flash file start loading from scratch every time the user visit the page with no cache.

Is there a way to preload and cache .swf files in my asp.net page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this page http://demo.swfupload.org/Documentation/#settingsobject  which describes there how to setup the swfupload object parameters, and i found a very useful parameter: `prevent_swf_caching : false,` which made my object caches on the page, and also loading faster.

Comment: I'm looking into doing the same optimization. Have you had any problems with IE doing this? (as that's the reason for prevent_swf_caching).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using a [cache manifest](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/offline.html)?
It is made for offline web applications, but maybe could help also with your problem.